# Get data replacing text between braces()

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, charindex

I have a table where the location data can be in 3 different formats like mentioned below

1. United States (US);New York (NY)
2. United States (US);New York
3. United States;New York

I have to pull all the records with all the 3 formats mentioned above.
So, I have tried replacing the content in braces with empty and then started comparing.

The query is

```
select * from TaxonomyLocations_Archive 
where REPLACE(REPLACE(TaxonomyHierarchy, 
SUBSTRING(TaxonomyHierarchy, 
CHARINDEX('(', TaxonomyHierarchy), 
CHARINDEX(')', TaxonomyHierarchy) - 
CHARINDEX('(', TaxonomyHierarchy) + 1), ''), 
' ;', ';') ='United States;New York'
```

But the above query is only comparing data till the first occurrence of the brackets and only returning matches with the 2nd and 3rd formats [`United States (US);New York` and `United States;New York`].

please suggest me the changes that I have to do to make it work for the 1st format [`United States (US);New York (NY)`] as well.

Comment: This feels like you should be fixing the source data so that you don't have 3 different values for the *same* value.

Comment: That syntax, however, isn't going to be performant. Why not use an `IN`?

Comment: Create an extra column with sanitized data, and search over this one. Don't sanitize on the fly.

Comment: What happens if your data is `New York; United States` can you guarantee the city always follows the country? What if someone uses `USA` etc?

Comment: @Stu - my data will always be in the format Country; City and not just codes alone in the country data.
only the mentioned 3 formats will be there in the database

Answer (score 0):

Variant:

```
select * from TaxonomyLocations_Archive 
where TaxonomyHierarchy like 'United States%' AND TaxonomyHierarchy like '%;New York%'
```